# Create title slug + random string Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, title, slug

I would like to create a slug that combines the title + a random string in Laravel.

I tried this, but nothing, in the second case it does nothing but combine the character string with the title.

```
Str::slug(request('title'), '-', Str::random());
```

or

```
Str::slug(request('title'), Str::random());
```

I would like something like this:

> this-is-an-example-title-Jfij4jio4523q234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Str::Slug()` has been defined as:

```
slug(string $title, string $separator = '-', string $language = 'en')
```

The third param can be seen as `language` with default value: `en`.

```
Str::slug($request->input('title').Str::random(40), '-');
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Double-check the method signature from https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-str-slug (and deeper at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L552)

To be explicit, the second parameter of the method is the character used to replace whitespace, and the third parameter refers to the locale to use when generating the slug. That means you need your string to be fully composed before passing it to the method.

Assuming you want your slug joined by a `-` then something like this is what you want:

```php
$value = request('title') . ' ' . Str::random();
$slug = Str::slug($value); // optionally Str::slug($value, '-'); to explicitly define the join
```

Comment: Or concatenated in the method call, like `Str::slug(request('title') . ' ' . Str::random());`, whatever is cleaner/preferred.